# Wordpress - Condition with parent term

Tags: php, css, wordpress, html

I created a Custom Post Type "Produit" with a taxonomy "Produits".
Inside of it i created three parent term ("Securite", "Confort", "Fermeture") this three parents terms have child term and all child term have posts.

[image]

In my Home page i display all my child term

[image]

When i clicked on a item i'm redirect in child term page (exemple url: 'produits/securite/alarme/'). My problem is the three parents terms have three differents colors to display on the child term page.

```
"SECURITE" -> orange
"CONFORT" -> pink
"FERMETURE" -> blue
```

So i need to know what is the parent term of the child term to add the good colors in the page.

[image]

I searched in the wordpress conditions but i don't find the solution.
I don't know if my explains is clear but anyone know how can i make it ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the parent taxonomy by using the follow:

```
// Get the child term
$child = get_term($id, 'produits');

// get_term returns an object with "parent" as a variable.
// the "parent" variable will return the parent term ID, or 0 if there is no parent.
$parent = ($child->parent == 0) ? $child : get_term($child->parent, 'produits');
```

You can also use `wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy, $args );` to retrieve the terms of the post. From there you can loop through the returned terms and find the parents using the method noted above.

[WP Codex get_term()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term)

[WP Codex wp_get_post_terms()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms)